# how to explode a dataframe schema in databricks

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, distributed-computing, databricks

I have a schema that should be exploded, below is the schema

```
 |-- CaseNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Customers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Contacts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
```

I want my schema to be like this,

```
|-- CaseNumber: string (nullable = true)
|-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
|-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
```

or

```
+----------+---------------------+
| CaseNumber| FirstName| LastName|
+----------+---------------------+
|       1  |     aa    |      bb |
+----------|-----------|---------|   
|       2  |     cc    |      dd | 
+------------------------------- |
```

I am new to databricks, any help would be appreciated.thanks

[image: please click this for sample data]

Comment: You have to explode Array and should select Struct individual type

df.select("caseNumber",explode("Customers").as("customers")).select($"customers._1").as("firstName")
Please provide a sample data and I shall explain the code

Comment: I have used this code to explode the first array(Customers) but as you see from the top schema structure there is another "Contacts" array that has to be exploded next

val tempDf = exploded.select( $"CaseNumber", explode( $"Customers" ).as( "CustomersFlat" ))

Please see above for the sample data that is generated after I exploded customers array

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve it without using explode command -

```
case class MyCase(val Customers = Array[Customer](), CaseNumber : String
)

case class Customers(val Contacts = Array[Contacts]()
)

case class Contacts(val Firstname:String, val LastName:String
)

val dataset = // dataframe.as[MyCase]

dataset.map{ mycase => 

// return a Seq of tuples like - (mycase.caseNumber, //read customer's contract's first and last name )
//one row per first and last names, repeat mycase.caseNumber .. basically a loop
}.flatmap(identity)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can still do explode(customersFlat.contacts). I sure this something like this some while ago, so forgive me my syntax and let me know whether this works

```
df.select("caseNumber",explode("customersFlat.contacts").as("contacts").select("caseNumber","contacts.firstName","contacts.lastName")
```